# What's the Lie algebra associated to positive-defined Hermitian matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm studying *polar decomposition* $GL(n,\Bbb C)\cong U(n)\times Herm^+(n)$, where $Herm^+(n)$ are positive-defined Hermitian matrices. I was trying to understand what happens to the associated Lie algebras, and I was wondering what $Herm^+(n)$ Lie algebra would look like.

**What I tried:**
I know that considering $F:SL(n,\Bbb R)\to SL(n,\Bbb R):A\mapsto A^\top A$, since $SO(n)=F^{-1}(I_n)$, we can prove that $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is the space of skew-symmetric matrices by calculating $$\mathfrak{so}(n)=\ker (dF_{I_n})=\left\{A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n} : \left. \frac d{dt}\right\vert_{t=0}F(I_n+tA)=0\right\}.$$
I wondered if I could do something similar for $Herm(n)$, defining $G:\Bbb C^{n\times n}\to\Bbb C^{n\times n}:A\mapsto A^*-A$ and $Herm(n)=G^{-1}(O_n)$, but I then realised that being $Herm(n)$ a linear subspace of $\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ I would just find $Herm(n)$ again. Is this a correct answer? Is $Herm(n)$ itself its own associated Lie algebra (with the commutator as Lie bracket)?
And what about positive-defined ones? What useful characterization may I take advantage of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hermitian matrices (positive-definite or otherwise) aren't closed under multiplication so they aren't a Lie group and don't have a Lie algebra. They also aren't closed under commutator bracket so they aren't themselves a Lie algebra either. However, they are $i$ times the skew-Hermitian matrices $\mathfrak{u}(n)$, which do form a Lie algebra (this requires that we ignore positive-definiteness), and we do have

$$\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathfrak{u}(n) \oplus i \mathfrak{u}(n).$$

In other words, every matrix $M$ is uniquely the sum of a skew-Hermitian matrix $\frac{M - M^{\dagger}}{2}$ and a Hermitian matrix $\frac{M + M^{\dagger}}{2}$. This is the Lie algebra incarnation of polar decomposition; despite not being a Lie algebra, there is still an exponential map from Hermitian matrices to positive-definite Hermitian matrices.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you so much. So, this decomposition $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\Bbb C)\cong\mathfrak{u}(n)\oplus i\mathfrak{u}(n)$ has nothing to do with "deriving" Lie algebras (in the sense that it can't be derived from polar decomposition of the matrix groups above), am I right?

Comment: @Ottavio: it does not follow from taking the derivative, no. It’s also not true that the exponential of the decomposition above gives a polar decomposition (unless the two components commute, e.g. when $n = 1$). I actually don’t have a good handle on what’s going on here.

Comment: Indeed, positive-definite Hermitian matrices aren't closed under standard matrix multiplication. But there are if we consider instead of the matrix multiplication, the operator: $A \cdot B = \textrm{expm}(\textrm{logm}(A) + \textrm{logm}(B))$ for any $A, B \in Herm^+(n)$ and where $\textrm{expm}$ and $\textrm{logm}$ are the matrix exponential and matrix logarithms resp. (for Hermitian matrices, these are the matrices obtained by taking the exponential or logarithm of their eigenvalues). Seems to me that this should define a Lie group right? In which case, what would its Lie algebra be? Thanks

Comment: @Charles: that operation is abelian so its Lie algebra has the trivial bracket.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, my math are a bit rusty and I forgot what that implies. Does that mean the vector space of its Lie algebra is $Herm(n)$?

Comment: Yes, you've just written the addition on Hermitian matrices in a funny way. A vector space regarded as an abelian Lie group is its own Lie algebra.